# Release C++ code using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, release

I have written a C++ project using Visual Studio 2017 in Windows 10. I am trying to run the code in other computers as well.

So, I tried copying the Release folder to another Windows 10 computer. But, when I try to execute the .exe file, it is showing errors: missing dll’s: vcruntime140.dll and ucrtbased.dll.

Please help me in the release process to be followed.

Comment: You need to distribute the compilers runtime libraries alongside your application. Search for "Microsoft visual studio redistributables".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because your application is dynamically loading the VC runtime which gets installed with the Redistributable package. Typically people can install the Redistributable packages without the full SDK but the easier solution is to just compile your application to statically load the C runtime libraries. 
Go to project settings, then C/C++->Code generataion and change your runtime library from /MD to /MT. /MD is dynamic and /MT is static.

Also you can just install the package on your other machine from here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: That's not always an option. 1) static linking bloats your executable. 2) static linking is not always possible. 3) when using open source libraries static linking may, in many cases, violate the license.

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes in some cases that's not always an option. I wasn't answering a general case. I was answering specifically for the question the user asked. I also provided an alternative by giving the user a link to the VC Redistributable package.

Comment: @Nina I tried installing the VC redistributable package, but the error still persists.

Comment: @NavinRahim Which one did you install? I believe VC140 is for Visual Studio 2015. So try instaling the 2015 redistributable package. Also if the packages don't work, you can just do a static compilation using the instructions I wrote above.

Comment: @Nina I installed the 2015,2017 and 2019 C++ redistributable(seems like the same package for all three versions). I also tried the static compilation step that is mentioned, but both methods are showing the dll's missing error.

Comment: Are you compiling as debug or release?

Comment: @Nina It worked. I had to do the static compilation process for the other libraries that were related to this project. Thanks for the help.